# Limiting length of text added to an HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am building a tree structure engine using an HTML5 canvas. Each tree node has a name that is read along with several other values from a database. Each node is represented by a block, the size of which is fixed. My problem is that the name of the block is often too long to fit onto the block. How can I determine how long (in width) a piece of text is going to be before adding it to the canvas, and how can I cut it off if it is going to be too long?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context.measureText("some text").width;`

Comment: Many thanks Paul. That gives me the length! Now I just need to figure out how to truncate it if it is too long :)

Comment: Something like this? `var text = "this is my message"; while(context.measureText(text).width > 300) text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);`

Comment: I was actually just playing around with something like that. Many thanks once again!

Comment: For anyone looking for a similar fix, I wrote this here function :) `function LimitText (text) { var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1'); var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); while (ctx.measureText(text).width > 140 /*add your limit here*/) text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1); return text; }`